# While compiling the word count topology I have a error in storm ui.The error is present at the "split" part of the bolt status

Tags: apache-storm

The Error is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when launching multilang subprocess

    at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.prepare(ShellBolt.java:105)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3493$fn__3505.invoke(executor.clj:689)
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__457.invoke(util.clj:431)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The pipe has been ended
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:260)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:106)
    at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.writeString(ShellProcess.java:77)
    at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.writeMessage(ShellProcess.java:70)
    at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:60)
    at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.prepare(ShellBolt.java:102)
    ... 4 more
```

Please help me to how to recover the error.And also give a path to work with storm.

Thanks,
Sowmiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have python installed in the machine you are trying to run this. The wordcount topology uses the `splitsentence.py` and it looks like its having problem while trying to run a bolt written in python. If you are not going to work with `multilang` you can ignore this and should be fine. Try running a simple one if you are going to be familiar with how storm works.

Comment: you can checkout the [storm starter project](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter) and run the exclamation topology example sample

Comment: we have tried but we are using a storm 9.1 version.The class files in the storm starter project throws an error as the class file cannot support this version of storm.Please guide us

Comment: `The class files in the storm starter project throws an error as the class file cannot support this version of storm.` -- could you please clarify this with some more details